# How do you reference DIV in Python (HTMLParsing)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Here's the website: http://scores.suntimes.com/sports-scores/Hockey-Scores-Matchups.aspx?Year=2013&Period=0119&CurrentSeason=2012-2013

Now, unlike the yahoo page I did earlier, the date here seems to be enclosed like this:

```
<div id="Scoreboard_6_National_Hockey_League">
         <div class="sdi-title-page-section">National Hockey League</div>
         <div class="sdi-nfl-dates">Saturday, January 19, 2013</div>
```

So if I wanted to extract that date, how would I word it out in Python?

Answer (score 1):

With `BeautifulSoup`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> html = """<div id="Scoreboard_6_National_Hockey_League">
...          <div class="sdi-title-page-section">National Hockey League</div>
...          <div class="sdi-nfl-dates">Saturday, January 19, 2013</div>"""
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> print soup.find('div', {'class':'sdi-nfl-dates'}).text
Saturday, January 19, 2013
```